# oauth2client TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, typeerror, gspread, oauth2client

**Set-up**

I'm using [gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) to manipulate a google sheet with Python.

All used to work fine, but now I'm getting an error when I try to use the credentials.

All is set-up according to the [great manual on Twillio](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html).

---

**Code**

```
os.chdir('/Users/path/to/client_secret.json')

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

Running this code gives the following error,

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-182-3638a9b3d45b>", line 5, in <module>
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 223, in from_json_keyfile_name
    revoke_uri=revoke_uri)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 189, in _from_parsed_json_keyfile
    revoke_uri=revoke_uri)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py", line 108, in __init__
    revoke_uri=revoke_uri)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/client.py", line 1472, in __init__
    super(AssertionCredentials, self).__init__(

TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/  There must be something wrong with `self` in the last line in the traceback, a debugger will help to see what.

Comment: @LucSpan did you end up figuring out what caused this?

Comment: Nope. It magically started working again the other day.